# Storing Local variables in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly

So I've been working on a problem (and before you ask, yes, it is homework, but I've been putting in faithful effort!) where I have some assembly code and want to be able to convert it (as faithfully as possible) to C.

Here is the assembly code:

```
A1:
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp, %ebp
 subl $16, %esp
 movl $0, -4(%ebp)
 jmp .L2
.L4:
 movl -4(%ebp), %eax
 sall $2, %eax
 addl 8(%ebp), %eax
 movl (%eax), %eax
 cmpl 12(%ebp), %eax
 jg .L6
.L2:
 movl -4(%ebp), %eax
 cmpl 16(%ebp), %eax
 jl .L4
 jmp .L3
.L6:
 nop
.L3:
 movl -4(%ebp), %eax
 leave
 ret
```

And here's some of the C code I wrote to mimic it:

```
int A1(int a, int b, int c) {
    int local = 0;
    while(local < c) {
        if(b > (int*)((local << 2) + a)) {
            return local;
        }
    }
return local;
}
```

I have a few questions about how assembly works.
First, I notice that in L4, the body of the while loop, nothing is ever assigned to local. It's initialized to be 0 at the start of the function, and then never modified again. Looking at the C code I made for it, though, that seems odd, considering that the loop will go on indefinitely if the if-condition fails. Am I missing something there? I was under the impression that you'd need a snippet of code like:

```
movl %eax, -4(%ebp)
```

in order to actually assign anything to the local variable, and I don't see anything like that in the body of the while loop.

Secondly, you'll see that in the assembly code, the only local variable that's declared is "local". Hence, I have to use a snippet of code like:

```
if(b > (int*)((local << 2) + a))
```

The output of this line doesn't look much like the assembly code, though, and I think I might have made a mistake. What did I do wrong here?

And finally (thanks for your patience!), on a related note, I understand that the purpose of this if-loop in the while loop is to break out if the condition is fulfilled, and then to return local. Hence L6 and "nop" (which is basically saying nothing). However, I don't know how to replicate this in my program. I've tried "break", and I've tried returning local as you see here. I understand the functionality - I just don't know how to replicate it in C (short of using goto, but that kind of defeats the purpose of the exercise...).

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The loop in your C code will either run infinitely or return during the first iteration, depending on whether the `if` condition is true, because it doesn't update any of the variables.

Comment: @Barmar I'm aware. I was trying to imitate the Assembly code, and like I said, I don't see where the assembly code updates the local variable anywhere. :L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my guess:

```
int A1 (int *a, int value, int size)
{
  int i = 0;

  while (i<size)
  {
    if (a[i] <= value)
      break;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Which, compiled back to assembly, gives me this code:

```
A1:
.LFB0:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $16, %esp
        movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
        jmp     .L2
.L4:
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        addl    %edx, %eax
        movl    (%eax), %eax
        cmpl    12(%ebp), %eax
        jg      .L2
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        cmpl    16(%ebp), %eax
        jl      .L4
.L3:
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        leave
        ret
```

Now this seems to be identical to your original ASM code, just the code starting at L4 is not the same, but if we anotate both codes:

ORIGINAL

```
movl    -4(%ebp), %eax    ;EAX = local
sall $2, %eax             ;EAX = EAX*4
addl 8(%ebp), %eax        ;EAX = EAX+a, hence EAX=a+local*4
```

ASM-C-ASM

```
movl    -4(%ebp), %eax    ;EAX = i
leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx  ;EDX = EAX*4
movl    8(%ebp), %eax     ;EAX = a
addl    %edx, %eax        ;EAX = EAX+EDX, hence EAX=a+i*4
```

Both codes continue with

```
movl    (%eax), %eax
```

Because of this, I guess `a` is actually a pointer to some variable type that uses 4 bytes. By the comparison between the second argument and the value read from memory, I guess that type must be either `int` or `long`. I choose `int` solely by convenience.

Of course this also means that this code (and the original one) does not make any sense. It lacks the `i++` part somewhere. If this is so, then `a` is an array, and the third argument is the size of the array. I've named my local variable `i` to keep with the tradition of naming index variables like this.

This code would scan the array searching for a value inside it that is equal or less than `value`. If it finds it, the index to that value is returned. If not, the size of the array is returned.